# SQLite Select Query Optimization

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to optimize a query that retrieves the volume for each month within a specified time range (e.g. 12 months in this case). The table contains about ~500k records and the query that I have takes 2473 ms to retrieve the data even with index. How else can I optimize this query?

```
QUERY USED:
    select strftime('%Y-%m', reported_date) as 'timeframe',
    count(*) as 'volume' 
    from [incident] 
    where (reported_date between '2018-06-01 00:00:00' and '2019-05-31 23:59:59') 
    and (priority = 'High')
    group by strftime("%Y-%m", reported_date)
```

```
 INDEX USED:
        create index 'incident_idx' ON 'incident' (
        'reported_date',
        'affected_service',
        'priority',
        'status',
        'event_type',
        'breach_status'
    );
```

[image: explain]

[image: explain query plan]

Comment: What's the `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` output? I doubt that index is being used in any meaningful way. It looks more like a table definition...

Comment: @Shawn Oh, I missed that! I've updated the post.

Comment: Try an index on `(priority, reported_date)`. That way both parts of the `WHERE` should be looked up in the index, not just the date.